# Getting unique value from core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsarray, nsset

I have two entities: `Schedule` and `User`. `Schedule` has a relationship `students`, which is  many to one with `User` (with an inverse of `studentSchedule`).

I have all the required `Schedule` objects in an array called `results`, but I want to actually get the unique `User`s from the `students` relationship.

I am using:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [results valueForKeyPath:@"students"]);
```

But I am not getting the correct result as I think due to to Many relation. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [CollectionOperators](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html).

```
NSLog(@"%@", [results valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.students"]);
```